# Vipassana meditation in day to day life

Tags: personal-practice, vipassana

During meditation practice have seen thinking stops ,then for 2 or 3 minutes no thinking. What have experienced?is it the pure mind?

Answer (score 2):

In Vipassana meditation, the primary focus centers on our own body and its various parts to cultivate detachment and alleviate desires related to the self. This meditation encourages a profound exploration, contemplating the impermanent and even repulsive aspects of the body. The objective is to comprehend that there is nothing permanent to cling to, as both our physical form and our soul undergo ceaseless change. This realization highlights the inevitability of change and mortality, applicable to all beings across all worlds. The ultimate goal of Vipassana meditation is to attain a deeper understanding of truth, relinquish attachment, and embark on the path to enlightenment.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not the pure mind (assuming of course you have a clear idea of what you mean when you use the label 'pure mind' along with the implications). What you experienced is that which you wrote- "...thinking stops, then for 2 or 3 minutes no thinking". In other words, what you have written at the beginning of your question is what you experienced.

Comment: Two parts of mind are experienced. One is thinking, other one is pop up without any involvement and very slow  in action. Are they javana citta and bavanga citta respectively?want to know what stage  the meditation  practice is?

Comment: @BuddhikaKitsiri- In my understanding, these aren't parts of mind. Rather, a better term would be that the mental states that you observed/experienced, were two different kinds of mental states. CItta is the sanskrit term for 'mind' (not brain, soul, etc.; mind). When it is used as cittas (in english), it refers usually to mental states. The two that you point out, are mental states. The two that you refer- javana' and 'bavanga' are very specific mental states (Buddha identifies 52 mental states which are important for reaching the end of the path; there are infinitely more mental states).

Comment: @BuddhikaKitsiri- Firstly, One can, as an example, maintain focus on object of meditation for say 10 minutes, without wavering. But more skilled meditator can do the same for an hour, say. Still more skilled meditator can maintain that attention for 10 hours, say. Yet more skilled and advanced meditators can 'go in' and 'come out' of these meditative states as and how they wish. It is not only having these mental states, or just being aware/mindful of them or maintain attention fir a few minutes. It is also the quality in terms of clarity and duration of those mental states.

Comment: @BuddhikaKitsiri- Secondly, and more importantly, the terms you have used are translated and understood slightly differently. Without knowing exactly how you are using them, I cannot be more precise with my own humble response to your query, to the best of my understanding